# wants to provide password to tightvnc server by using script

Tags: ruby, vnc

I am installating tightvnc server on my ubuntu machine by using ruby script my script contain following:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby env    
`sudo apt-get --force-yes -y install tightvncserver`
`printf "%s\n%s\n" "demo123" "demo123" | vncserver :1`
```

I used printf way because vncserver ask for password on terminal, But that way failed, Is their any better way to solve this?

I wants to provide password using ruby script so that terminal not prompt and ask user to provide password.Hope this clear

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142978/is-there-an-expect-equivalent-gem-for-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment the stackoverflow post, have a look at expect, there are several [examples](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/83119) kicking around.